# how do you document padrino route methods using rdoc?

Tags: web-services, padrino, rdoc

I'd like to use RDoc to document API calls in a web services app written in Padrino.  Here's an example file:

```ruby
Analytics.controller :api do
  diable :layout

  ##
  # = <base_url>/ping - test for response
  # The +ping+ command is a quick way to verify a live connection to the
  # service.
  get :ping, :provides => :json do
    {:time => timestamp(), :version => version_string()}.to_json
  end

end
```

But since there's no surrounding Class, rdoc doesn't create documentation for the :ping method.  Of course I can document the API calls in a separate file using rdoc or markup, but that seems so twentieth-century.

How do other people handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Padrino is based on Sinatra, documenting routes is doable with this gem [yard-sinatra](https://github.com/rkh/yard-sinatra).

Comment: Just as an aid to future searchers, this doesn't work.